# Text File Parsing in C - Calling a Batch File Or Not

Tags: c, parsing, batch-file, arguments

This website is a tremendous source of knowledge, it has helped me countless times in the past.

I just started learning **C** on my own - up until now I just wrote a few batch files.

So I humbly ask for your help - I'd like some guidelines on how to write a C program that would:

- 1) Open a text file that contains the following

`"batch1.cmd" "argument1" "1"`

`"batch2.cmd" "argument2" "0"`

`"batch3.cmd" "argument3" "1"`

- 2) Parse it to find "0" or "1"

  **If "1"** call he specified batch file with its argument

  **If "0"** go next line - I will be updating the text file on a regular basis, so I would just have to change 1 or 0 and not rewrite all of those lines.

I have found a lot of help regarding parsing in **C** on the internet already, but no tutorial regarding how to achieve that.
I am aware that this might seem very easy and that I must appear as someone very lazy but I assure you I've been at it for three days now, without any success.

I am not necessarily asking for a complete script, just an answer like "look into the following function, its correct syntax is yadda yadda" and so forth.

I think I would have to use

`int Search_in_File(char *fname, char *str)`

`{ FILE *fp;`

`fp=fopen("c:\\batchlist.txt", "r");`

and

`system("c:\\batch1.cmd argument1");`

but I somehow cannot "connect the dots."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've opened the file. Next thing (after checking that `fopen` was successful) is to read from it. Consider `fread` and `fgets`, decide which you prefer for this task.

Comment: For this task, especially given it is a text file, fgets() is probably best for you. Don't forget to fclose() the file when you're finished with it!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to make your file itself a batch file and overwrite the first 4 characters of the line with either `"    "` (4 spaces) or `"rem "` to enable/disable a line?

Comment: @David: Do you have to use **C**? This is something I would be tempted to write as a batch file itself.

Comment: If it not for homework, I would recommend to move the 0/1 flag to be the first argument in each line. It will make parsing much easier.

Comment: @Steve Jessop thanks, that's what I was looking for!  @AlastairG I didn't even know I needed to use fclose(), thanks.  @R.. In a way, yes. I think I'll apply eyalm's suggestion to rearrange my BatchList.txt so that each line starts with "0" or "1"  @eyalm This is very helpful, and unfortunately no I'm not studying anymore, it's just that I have a lot of batch files for scheduled tasks, and I thought it'd be easier to do just one task in C, as this language offers a bit more than the standard Batch language in terms of options and so forth.  Thanks everyone, merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output - you're very close.  Once you've opened the file, you need to read the lines or characters from the file, and based on what you find, execute the `system` command.

That wiki page will show you how - it has some handy example code too :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for replying a bit late, I had a network problem. Thanks a lot for your input, I think I'm getting really close. I need to find the correct syntax of "if" "else goto next line" and so forth, but I can feel I'm there! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
int Search_in_File(char *fname, char *str)

{ FILE *fp;
char line[100],a[100],b[100],c[100];
fp=fopen("c:\\batchlist.txt", "r");
if( !fp ) ... errorhandling here ...
while( fgets(line,100,fp) )
{
  if( strchr(line,'\n') ) *strchr(line,'\n')=0;
  if( 3==sscanf(line,"%s%s%s",a,b,c) && !strcmp(c,"1") ) /* "%s" breaks at whitespaces, attention for whitespaces in your strings here! */
  {
    sprintf(line,"%s %s",a,b);
    system(line);
  }
}
...
fclose and so on ...
}
```